# A value of type 'xxx?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'xxx' because 'xxx?' is nullable and 'xxx' isn't

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning `factory method` in dart. However I encounter a problem, which says

> A value of type 'Person?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Person' because 'Person?' is nullable and 'Person' isn't.
> 3-1.dart:13

Here is my code:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  Person a = new Person("zarkli");
  a.say("hello");
}

class Person{
  final name;
  static final Map<String, Person> _cache = new Map<String,Person>();

  factory Person(String name){
    if (_cache.containsKey(name)){
      return _cache[name]; // error
    } else {
      final person = new Person.newPerson(name);
      _cache[name] = person;
      return person;
    }
  }
  Person.newPerson(this.name);
  
  void say(String content){
    print("$name: $content");
  }
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety read this blog to understand null safety

Comment: check `Map.putIfAbsent` method - that way you will replace your 7 lines of your factory constructor code with just one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some maps allow null as a value. For those maps, a lookup using this operator cannot distinguish between a key not being in the map, and the key being there with a null value.

This is from the get operator [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) for map. When you use `containsKey` it could be the case that the key exists but its value is null.
You can use a local variable to store `_cache[name]` and check if it's null or not. Dart then can promote that local variable and not give you any errors. So your factory will look like this:

```
factory Person(String name) {
    final cached = _cache[name];
    if (cached != null) {
      return cached;
    } else {
      final person = Person.newPerson(name);
      _cache[name] = person;
      return person;
    }
}
```